# WebAPI and MVC on separate Machines

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I have both a design question along with an overall question of the way WebAPI works.

We have an Internal Website that houses many applications ( a seperate MVC Area for each application). We then have sectioned out the DAL Logic into libraries that are front ended by Web Service calls. The Models/Repositories will call to CRUD things inside several databases (some internal, some third party). So It looks like this

UI -> Model-> Repository -> WebServices -> DB.

This was originally done because we needed to be able to access multiple data access points and funnel them back to the Internal Website for various applications and it seemed like a good way to abstract out all the logic so that the Web Application only focuses on the View end. This pattern has proven to be good for seperation of concerns, but now we are looking into making this available to more than just .NET applications/clients and that points me to begin to look at WebAPI.

Here are my questions:

1. My main question is, knowing that the Web Services are all done in WCF ( contract based), how hard would it be to convert this to using WebAPI keeping in mind that we wish to make sure the WebAPI webservice is on a separate server from the UI.
2. Is there any way to set up WebAPI to have contracts and still use the HTTP verbs?

   - If i am remotely accessing the WebAPI web service via an MVC application on another server and another solution, is there any way to still get that strongly typed objects that you get when you consume a WCF contract?
3. What are people's thoughts on this design pattern?